# What is the best practice of using event_scheduler in mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I used event_scheduler to schedule event on mariadb and it seems work so well initially but after just 3 days the whole thing take a turn as my database stop working and giving out of memory error, I try to reconnect and immediately it will go off again, I was left without any option so I was forced to get my data off and uninstall mariadb and reinstall it again after which I delete the event I already schedule, now I need to schedule an event again but am afraid of running into the same problem, I read of event_scheduler causing memory leak and I thought the could be the case in my situation, so I'd like to know what is the safest way of using event_scheduler. My initial event is below

```
CREATE EVENT `update_market_status`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND
 STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO  
    UPDATE `market` SET `status`=2 WHERE  `date` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

My question is: could this above code have being behind the memory leak? if yeah what is the best way to actualize this effect. am open to any suggestion, thanks for your time all

Also below is the table definition for `market`

[image]

and the reason I want to run the event constantly is  because I need to keep track of which games is the `date` already in the past and update the status of the game as the game time are different and fixed so I can't fix a specific time to run the event but there's any other method to actualize this it's also ok

the result of the show create table is below

```
CREATE TABLE `market` (
  `market_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `league_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_team` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `away_team` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'wether the market is real or demo',
  `score` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`market_id`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `league_id` (`league_id`),
  KEY `home_team` (`home_team`),
  KEY `away_team` (`away_team`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_market_away_team` FOREIGN KEY (`away_team`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_market_country` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_market_home_team` FOREIGN KEY (`home_team`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_market_league` FOREIGN KEY (`league_id`) REFERENCES `leagues` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=521 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Please publish table definition for market - and is there a reason event needs to run constantly.

Comment: Please add the result of show create table<tablename> (the published table image does not show indexes)

Comment: @P.Salmon I already added the result of show create table, thanks for your time